# GL_INTENSITY16 Alternative?

Tags: opengl, opengl-4, pixelformat

I have a texture that used to be read in as GL_INTENSITY16 internal pixel format. After upgrading the pipeline ive noticed GL_INTENSITY16 is deprecated though i can kind of load the texture with GL_COMPRESSED_INTENSITY but the texture is very faint and barely visible. Some gamma correction and im able to see it but i lose a lot of data due to the curve. Is there a method of loading in a texture that is more similar to GL_INTENSITY16? Any examples would be really helpful.

Comment: `GL_R16`? A red-only texture is the typical way single channel textures are created.

Comment: @Blindy That one works but again its very faint to the point where the texture can't be seen at all without the same gamma correction. I tried to do some debugging with renderDoc and the texture does get sent to the shaders and all correctly but opening the texture resource and looking at the data in renderDoc the highest pixel value it reports is 0.00324 which is pretty low lol i think glPixelTransfer functions needed to be used before and im trying to replicate those in the frag shader. It also had glTexEnvf set to modulate now that i think about it

Comment: It sounds like you're doing some kind of gamma correction on your data. Check the texture transfers you're doing, you have to be using sRGB somewhere. Or some alpha-blending if you're not just straight uploading your texture data, but are computing it. We'd need a lot more information to help with this though, or at least a **small** reproduction.

Comment: @Marauder2k9 Well that is up to you and your texture data. If the highest pixel value is 0.00324 it's because you are telling it to make the highest pixel value 0.00324. It sounds like you don't really know what the computer is doing with the texture. You should figure out what you want the computer to do and then ask how to do that.

Comment: @Blindy I found out that the format has min max ranges baked into it along with gamma correction level that I needed to use in the shader to adjust the values (pow clamp all that good stuff), not an ideal format but some of these older renderers used to do some..... questionable things lol thanks for your help